# Read QR Code (JSON string) with jquery scanner and put values in different input fields in a web page

Tags: jquery

I need to read a QR CODE for Electronic Invoice (Fattura elettronica in Italy) containt different fields value coded as JSON string.

Example of a working string:

```
{"anag":{"naz":"IT","cf":"01234567890","piva":"01234567890","denom":"AZIENDA TEST SRL","domFisc":{"prov":"PN","cap":"33170","com":"PORDENONE","ind":"VIA DI PROVA 1","naz":"IT"}},"dtGenQr":"2018-06-20T22:04:32.102+0200","SDI":{"pec":"testpec@legalmail.it","cod":"0000000"}}
```

And in attachment the generated QR CODE.[image]

My goal is to use a BARCODE / QRCODE SCANNER (hardware) connected to PC.
I'd like to open a page with a form like:

```
...
<form>
  <input type="text" name="naz" id="naz" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="cf" id="cf" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="piva" id="piva" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="denom" id="denom" value="">
  ...
</form>
```

And when I press the button on the scanner, i need to autocompile differents input with value get from qrcode result (that is a json string).

BUT I know scanner works like a keyboard, so the result is pasted inside a focused input.

Is there a way to intercept the code scanner, split values with jquery, and paste each value inside correct input field?

like:

```
function parse_code_scanned() {

  var result = ""; //get value fron scanner (string - json)

  var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON( result );

  $("#naz").val(parsed.anag.naz);

  $("#cf").val(parsed.anag.cf);

  ...

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // on event (code-scanned) run this function

  parse_code_scanned();

});
```

My first problems are: - what jquery plugin do I use to use a generic scanner? - How can read a event? - how can i get value from scanner without put in inside a input field (i don't want to put my entire string-json in a input or if it's necessary, I can put in in a input hidden to manipulate it)?